# What is the difference between HttpApplication class and IHttpModule?

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between HttpApplication class and IHttpModule? Are they both same or different?

I see articles that mention the same events in both the classes.

Comment: *Same events* yes as long as they're request-level events. But not when they're application-level events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpApplication` is the web application instance that has multiple `IHttpModule` instances  registered in it. That's why every `IHttpModule` instance handles a certain part of application execution thus can usually be reused on many applications (think of a `Session` handling module or authentication module).

In terms of application/request handling there are many similarities. `HttpApplication` has access to application-level events like **OnStart**, **OnEnd** etc as well as request-level events like **OnBeginRequest**, **OnEndRequest** etc. `IHttpModule` on the other hand only has access to request-level events.

> **Additional note**: It's possible to handle application start and end events even using an IHttpModule, but this is a non-documented feature and you have to take some special precautions. Check these two blog posts that explain it all into great depth:
>   [Writing a custom `IHttpModule` that handles `Application_OnStart` event](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/08/writing-ihttpmodule-thats-able-to.html)
>   [How to correctly use `IHttpModule` to handle `Application_OnStart` event](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-correctly-use-ihttpmodule-to.html)

I suggest you read a bit about application life cycle execution pipeline:

- [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating and Registering a Custom HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx)

Comment: +1 love learning new stuff every time I try and answer something!

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani: What? You don't believe me when I say that `HttpApplication` handles application-level events and `IHttpModule` implementations handle request-level events? ;)

Comment: when shld I be using either of them?

Comment: Use `IHttpModule` implementation for a modular and re-usability approach, Use `Global.asax.cs/vb` events in for application-only non-modular *lord of the rings* approach (one ring to rule them all). Sometimes when you have to rule certain application level events you don't have any other choice but to write a handler in a `Glogal.asax` codebehind. **FYI** Microsoft itself use the modular approach which actually conforms to [SoC principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). I tend to follow the same pattern which makes it simpler to maintain.

Comment: Robert.......Here is what I have done. I have created a BeginRequest handler and just done a Response.Write("Begin request handler reached").  I see the output on the browser , but without the cascading style sheet applied to the page. I dont understand why no stylesheet is applied!!

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani: Well you did send pure text to response stream, didn't you? How do you think a browser should style your text? I suggest you use Fiddler tool to see the actual response that is getting back to your browser (Firebug already changes it to its liking). You'll see exactly where does your *injected* text end up in your resulting HTML. Probably before `HTML` tag...

Comment: No No No.....I dont see the css applied to the page. I can see the page as it is but w/o stylesheet applied....I am trying to pass a variable using querystring and authenticate the use in authrequest event. However if i dont call this handler I see the stylesheet applied normally

Comment: @Chandan: As said previously: use Fiddler and check what's going on. Something must be wrong with our resulting HTML for browser to misinterpret it. Fiddler will show you what.

Comment: Ok ,  It does come before html tag but how do I use the authenticaterequest event to redirect the user to any other pagee.

Comment: @Chandan: What does the text pre-pending have to do with page redirection? If you want to redirect your user you should send them a 30x HTTP status and call `Response.End();` This will send the proper redirection to the browser that will make a request to a redirected resource.

Comment: Ok. Never mind that. When would I use application level events? can u give me a scenario?

Comment: @Chandan: Think of a web farm-wide resource that needs to be set when applications are active and needs to be disposed along with them as well. You could use `Disposed` event to handle such situation.

Comment: Robert. I think I am gonna put an end to this. Thanks buddy. You were very patient in answering my questions. Thanks!!

Comment: @Chandan: :) Of all the scarce information of what you're trying to accomplish you'll be probably better of putting it in an `IHttpModule` than writing it in `Global.asax` codebehind. The latter is mostly used for quick solutions.

Comment: you mean using a customized authentication in IHttpModule than using Global.asax AuthenticationRequest?

Comment: Yes. Use a module because it's functionality is related to a single aspect of the request process. Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any great difference other than HttpModules allow you to remove or separate the handling of an event from the rest of your application. This can help with code reuse, particularly across applications.
Furthermore, using this technique you can add in HttpModules to your application without having to change any existing source code (e.g. [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)) to provide extra functionality.

Answer (score 0):

http://aspalliance.com/442_Introducing_HTTPModules.all

Good article that should help your understanding of how HttpModules and HttpApplications work together.

Answer (score 0):

IHttpModule is a managed request handler, which means that implements "catches" for the request
life-cycle.

HttpApplication represents the Web server (IIS) ASP.NET application. Right, it has the events and other
members that you need in the context of an HTTP Module.

You may develop a HTTP module if you need to implement a customized way of handling some input data
given by some HTTP request. Obviously, that may require you to access the HTTP application, which is
the one exposing the request life-cycle events.

The summary is HTTP module is an observer of HTTP application that may implement logic in order to
process an HTTP request in the way the HTTP application signals every step of ASP.NET infraestructure
life-cycle.

Comment: Can u suggest me a nice article, which helps me understand the difference better

Comment: It's that easy, Chandan. HTTP Application "is the application" (your web site), while an HTTP Module is something like a "processor of a request to the application" :D

Comment: ASP.NET is hosted by Internet Information Server, a web server techonology present in all modern Windows. The directory where the web site resides is marked as "application". That "application" is the HttpApplication. But you need something to handle what happens with that HttpApplication. For example, you want to know if some web request to your web site has permission to load some data, you check some cookie and you compare some data to know if the user is authenticated and has authorization for some conent: This is done by an HttpModule, which is bound to the HttpApplication.